# Need help creating a sparse data matrix from a long character string of item IDs and item responses

Tags: r

[Edited to include data via `dput` and also to fix the regex string to match Item IDs.]

Suppose I have a data.frame composed of responses to a short online math test, where every test-taker answers 5 randomly selected items out of a possible 9 items, and suppose the data come to me like the following:

```
id    data
tt1   item01 0   item04 1    item03 1    item09 0    item05 0
tt2   item01 1   item06 1    item08 1    item02 0    item04 1
tt3   item05 1   item03 0    item07 1    item09 0    item02 1
```

I managed to parse the variable `data`, which is just a character string of five item-ID-and-right/wrong pairs, into a matrix of item responses that looks like this:

```
[1]      [2]      [3]      [4]      [5]
0        1        1        0        0
1        1        1        0        1
1        0        1        0        1
```

However, since test-takers were given a random selection of items, the columns don't correspond to unique items across test-takers. What I really need is a sparse matrix like this:

```
item01    item02    item03    item04    item05    item06    item07    item08    item09
0         NA        1         1         0         NA        NA        NA        0
1         0         NA        1         NA        1         NA        1         NA
NA        1         0         NA        1         NA        1         NA        0
```

My incredibly unwieldy and inefficient method is to create a data.frame with three columns (test-taker ID, item ID, and item score) which are all pre-populated and item scores are all recorded as NA. Then, I go through every row of that data.frame, look up whether that test-taker saw that item, and, if so, record whether they got a 0 or a 1 on that item. Then I transform the long data set into a wide data set, and I essentially have my sparse matrix of item responses. I know there has to be a better way to do this, but I either can't find the `tidyr` function that I know must exist out there somewhere, or I can't wrap my head around it, or both.

**Does anyone know of a more efficient method to create this sparse matrix than the monstrosity that I've come up with?**

Sample data:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(ID = c(224980L, 736740L, 233990L, 562350L, 199990L, 
558030L, 996830L, 320870L, 574270L, 452490L, 495630L, 578650L, 
933180L, 761630L, 211680L, 651880L, 777560L, 853740L, 738940L, 
764780L, 787330L, 354800L, 228320L, 618950L, 520450L, 718330L, 
672280L, 629630L, 452120L, 597330L, 542010L, 396550L), TEST_DATA = c("Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 1", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 1", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 0      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 0      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 0      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 0      Item606 0", 
"Item741 1      Item732 0      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 1", 
"Item741 1      Item732 1      Item743 1      Item602 1      Item606 0", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 1      Item489 0", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 1      Item489 1", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 0      Item488 1      Item489 1", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 1      Item489 0", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 0      Item489 1", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 1      Item489 0", 
"Item484 1      Item743 0      Item487 1      Item488 0      Item489 0", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 0      Item489 1", 
"Item484 1      Item743 1      Item487 1      Item488 0      Item489 1", 
"Item484 0      Item743 0      Item487 0      Item488 0      Item489 0", 
"Item484 0      Item743 1      Item487 0      Item488 0      Item489 0", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 0", 
"Item487 1      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 0      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 1      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 1      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 0      Item554 0", 
"Item487 1      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 1      Item606 1      Item554 1", 
"Item487 0      Item550 1      Item552 0      Item606 1      Item554 0", 
"Item487 1      Item550 0      Item552 1      Item606 0      Item554 0"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

Sample data can also be found here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AucYBk7HiTv6mcI7emgpAuI8dEYO-Q?e=fpI0lb

My code:

```
library(tidyr) # for function 'spread()'

M <- nrow(dat) # number of test-takers

# Get start and end position of each item ID in the long character string
varstart <- as.numeric(gregexpr(pattern = 'Item\\d{3}', text = dat$TEST_DATA[1], perl = TRUE)[[1]])
varend <- varstart + 7

# Get start and end position of each score (0/1) in the long character string
scorestart <- varstart + 13
scoreend <- varstart + 15

# Create non-sparse item response matrix
tmp_data <- lapply(dat$TEST_DATA, function(y) {
  as.numeric(substring(y, scorestart, scoreend))
})
data <- matrix(unlist(tmp_data), ncol = length(scorestart), byrow = TRUE)

# Get all unique item IDs
items <- lapply(dat$TEST_DATA, substring, varstart, varend)
all_items <- sort(unique(unlist(items))) # all unique items

# Create long data set
ldat <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(all_items) * length(dat$ID), ncol = 3))
names(ldat) <- c('ID', 'Item', 'Score')
for (i in 1:length(dat$ID)) {                                     # for each test-taker
  start <- (i-1) * length(all_items) + 1                          # start position in the long data set for this test-taker
  end <- start + length(all_items) - 1                            # end position in the long data set for this test-taker
  ldat$ID[start:end] <- rep(dat$ID[i], times = length(all_items)) # fill in the test-taker ID
  ldat$Item[start:end] <- all_items                               # fill in the unique item IDs
  for (j in 1:length(all_items)) {                                # for each unique item
    jpos <- start + j - 1                                         # track position in the long data set
    if (all_items[j] %in% items[[i]]) {                           # if test-taker i saw item j
      num <- which(items[[i]] == all_items[j])                    # find position of item j in test-taker i's item responses
      ldat$Score[jpos] <- data[i,num]                             # fill in 0/1 as appropriate
    }
  }
}

# Transform long data to wide
final_data <- spread(ldat, key='Item', value='Score')
```

Comment: @RonakShah Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use achieve this using `tidyr` functions.

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  separate_rows(TEST_DATA, sep = '\\s{2,}') %>%
  separate(TEST_DATA, c('item', 'value'), sep = '\\s') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = item, values_from = value)

#       ID Item741 Item732 Item743 Item602 Item606 Item484 Item487
#    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1 224980       1       1       1       1       1      NA      NA
# 2 736740       1       1       1       1       0      NA      NA
# 3 233990       1       1       1       1       1      NA      NA
# 4 562350       1       1       1       1       0      NA      NA
# 5 199990       1       0       1       1       0      NA      NA
# 6 558030       1       1       0       1       0      NA      NA
# 7 996830       1       0       1       1       0      NA      NA
# 8 320870       1       1       1       0       0      NA      NA
# 9 574270       1       0       1       1       1      NA      NA
#10 452490       1       1       1       1       0      NA      NA
# … with 22 more rows, and 5 more variables: Item488 <int>,
#   Item489 <int>, Item550 <int>, Item552 <int>, Item554 <int>
```

- Split the `TEST_DATA` in different rows splitting on two or more whitespace.
- Separate the value and item into different columns on whitespace.
- Get the data in wide format.

Comment: This works! Thank you for saving me from hours of staring at progress bars :)